# Color Picker in design:component?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, design-attributes, color-picker

Any ideas on how to add a color picker into the .design component of a Lightning bundle? There's [nothing in the docs](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/components_config_for_app_builder_design_files.htm) and I don't know how to insert lightning:input with type="color" into the design file.

I am using dynamic picklists, using an Apex class as the datasource. Can't figure a way to do the color picker though...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a thought, suppose you have a Component that you want to be configurable with a custom UI more complex than App Builder can handle... what you could conceivably do is create a Setup tab that saves component setups in Custom Metadata or such. Then your Design component can just have a dynamic picklist that chooses from the previously set-up configurations.

Answer (score 4):

You can't use anything other than Integer, Boolean, and String types in a component's design file. There's no way to insert any sort of "custom" component at all, as it is exposed by the app builder functionality.

Comment: Yeah, that's what Salesforce confirmed on the Success Community. I can imagine that others might have use for color picker, date picker, etc. Hope they add that in the future.

Answer (score 1):

Can't reply directly to @sfdcfox due to low rep.
Problem is that default components have color pickers, tabs, sliders, etc. in designer, like **CMS Collection**, for example. So designer and app builder actually have this functionality, it's just that Salesforce does not want to expose it to users, presumably because it's not tested well. But still, it's really sad that default components can have this and custom - not.